# How to get count of documents that match a certain condition in Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Suppose, I have a MongoDB query

```
db.tm_watch.count({trademark: {$in: [ObjectId('1'), ObjectId('2')]}});
```

that returns the count of documents that have trademark equal to 1 or 2.
I have tried this query to convert it into elasticsearch one.

```
 es_query = {
    "query": {
       "bool": {
          "must": [
                     {"terms": {"trademark": ids}},
                     {"term": {"team": req.user.team.id}},
                  ],
                }
              }
            }
 esClient.count({
    index: 'tm_watch',
    type: 'docs',
    body: es_query
}
```

but I don't know is this correct since I'm new to Elasticsearch.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ES equivalent to mongodb's `.count` method is the [Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html).

Assuming your index name is `tm_watch` and the field `trademark` has a [`.keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) mapping, you could use a [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

```
POST tm_watch/_count
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "trademark.keyword": [ "1", "2" ]
    }
  }
}
```